# React-Native can not rollout apk support 64bit

Tags: android, react-native

I have an apk support 64bit, but i can not rollout to product.

My apk is support 64bit:

Analyze:
[image]

Noti:
[image]

But when rollout:
[image]

Error message:

> Error This release is not compliant with the Google Play 64-bit
>   requirement
>
> The following APKs or App Bundles are available to 64-bit devices, but
>   they only have 32-bit native code: 8.
>
> Include 64-bit and 32-bit native code in your app. Use the Android App
>   Bundle publishing format to automatically ensure that each device
>   architecture receives only the native code it needs. This avoids
>   increasing the overall size of your app.

Any help please!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, your problem might be that you haven't updated the ndk part of your gradle file.

Search for ndk here:
https://medium.com/@andriidrozdov/reactnative-and-android-64-bit-new-google-play-market-rules-what-to-do-584b067d6f1a

Comment: Yes i have:

 ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
        }

Answer (score 0):

What is your react-native version? Must be at least v0.59.0 for 64-bit app.

Comment: Yes, my current version:
react: 16.8.3
react-native: 0.59.9

Answer (score 0):

`react-native version 0.59`  supports 64 bit native code.

> upgrade your project to 0.59.9 or letest

Comment: I upgrade to 0.60.5, but still rollout fail.

Comment: can you show me your android/app/build.gradle file ?

Comment: I clone my source code. create new project with new bundle, and submit to product success.
I think my current app cache the issue. so i can not submit new version.
with same keystore.

Answer (score -1):

I found the error:

> The following APKs or App Bundles are available to 64-bit devices, but they only have 32-bit native code: 8.

This error is just for build at code 8.
I just deactive build at code 8 then i can submit new version.

Comment: can you explain/show how you "deactivated build at code 8" ? @Tim